# `spl-token create-token` error when running

Tags: spl-token-cli

When running spl-token create-token it shows me this error:

```
error: Could not find config file
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: what version are you running, or are you building from source? there was a bug like this but i dont know that it made it into any release

Comment: I installed it using cargo. I did cargo install spl-token-cli. The version is v2.0.16. Is that the latest version?

Comment: hmm i just installed v2.0.16 via cargo install and it works fine for me, so i dont think its the issue i was thinking of. also re: the comments below, not having a config.yml file is fine. the cli falls back to defaults if its not there. id suggest trying a packaged release of the cli tools to see if that solves your problem https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

The `spl-token` configuration is shared with the solana command-line tool.

Try running `solana config get` to the path of the solana config file.
Use `spl-token -C <PATH>` to set it.

```
OPTIONS:
    -C, --config <PATH>           Configuration file to use
```

Comment: When I run solana config get it shows that my solana config file is in /home/user/.config/solana/cli/config.yml, when I go to the .config folder there is no cli folder and the config is in /home/user/.config/solana/install. I am using Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

many apologies, this is a regression in 2.0.16. i think i was accidentally calling the wrong binary when i originally attempted to investigate

im making a 2.0.17 that fixes this. in the mean time you can specify the config you actually have with `-C`, or downgrade to 2.0.15. the official release on the website has this version: https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools

update: 2.0.17 is now out

Answer (score 0):

Try to force reinstall spl-token-cli and then get the config again. You may also have to set the default signer. Following this trouble